# How to make 3 circles in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So I was given an assignment in which I had to make a graph with 3 circles.

I tried to make it by using 'make_circles' from sklearn.datsets. I used the code

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_circles
X_3 , Y_3 = make_circles(n_samples = 5609 , noise = 0.1 , factor = 0, random_state = 42)
plt.scatter(X_3[:, 0], X_3[:, 1])
plt.show()
```

It is resulting in only 2 circles. I want to insert another circle in the same graph. What to do? Kindly help as this assignment is very important for my grades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend you try to do your assignments yourself, as that will genuinely help you in the long run. But that's not what this site is for, so here goes:

You don't necessarily need Scikit-Learn to draw circles in a Matplotlib figure; Matplotlib supports drawing circles (and many more shapes) through so-called [patches](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/patches_api.html).

A [circle](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html) at (4, 6) with a radius of 2 can be instantiated as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
circle = plt.Circle((4, 6), 2)
```

This `Circle` object can be added to a figure using `Axes.add_patch`, for example (`plt.gca()` just grabs the current relevant `Axes` instance):

```
plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.gca().add_patch(circle)
plt.show()
```

This will give us our [circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41EHq.png). You may notice that the circle is not entirely... circular. As the documentation states, it's a 'true circle', meaning that it adheres to the scaling of the figure. You could manually fix this using an `Ellipse` instead of a `Circle`. However, that and how disable filling, linewidth, colours, etc., I will leave as an assignment to the reader.